# Microsoft.AspNet.WebApi 5.2.7 Routing Problem

Tags: asp.net, .net, asp.net-web-api, routes

We were using Microsoft.AspNet.WebApi 5.2.3 in our project and we recently have upgraded to 5.2.7 and some of the existing functionality stopped working:

I have this FileController:

```
[ApiVersion("1")]
[RoutePrefix("api/v{version:apiVersion}/file")]
public class FileController : BaseController
{
    [HttpPost]
    [MapToApiVersion("1")]
    [Route("uploadmethod"), Obsolete("The action is marked as obsolete for missing the support for userId. Please use uploadmethod from version 2.")]
    public async Task<HttpResponseMessage> UploadFileStream([FromUri] string filePath = null...)
    {

    }
}
```

And then another controller that derives from the one above:

```
[ApiVersion("2")]
[RoutePrefix("api/v{version:apiVersion}/file")]
public class FileController : Controllers.FileController
{
    [HttpPost]
    [MapToApiVersion("2")]
    [Route("uploadmethod")]
    public async Task<HttpResponseMessage> UploadFileWithUserId([FromUri] string userId = null, [FromUri] string filePath = null)
    {
       //at some point here I call an internal method from the base FileController
    }
}
```

When using 5.2.3, the following code was working fine:

```
$"api/v1/file/uploadmethod?filePath={path}";
```

Now, after upgrade to 5.2.7, I receive this error:
**"Multiple controller types were found that match the URL. This can happen if attribute routes on multiple controllers match the requested URL."**

I need the MapToApiVersion attribute because I need to test below to succeed.

```
    [Fact]
    public async Task UploadFileUsingVersion2NUserId_WillThrowError_MethodsIsMissingOnThatVersion()
    {       
            //...
            var url = $"api/v2/file/uploadmethod?filePath={path}";

            // When
            var response = await api.UploadFile(url, content);

            // Then
            Assert.Equal(HttpStatusCode.MethodNotAllowed, response.StatusCode);
            var errorResponse = await response.Content.ReadAsJsonAsync<UnsupportedVersionResponse>();
            Assert.Equal("UnsupportedApiVersion", errorResponse.Error.Code);
    }
```

What has changed? How can I enforce v1 only for the base controller?